# RoomHist is not working and "device not in this home" shown

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

Devices are not allocated to room after SYNC in a specific Google Home app.

I confirmed that devices are allocated to rooms in my app on my iphone for the same home,
but not allocated to rooms for the person who lives there.

We can control the decices (like turn on/off),
(49 devices mean all devices that connected through our service)
but it says "49 devices not in a home".

I appreciate if any one can give me a clue to solve this.

App version: 2.49.196

I asked the person to delete all existing devices and rooms that connected, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Devices are not allocated to rooms after SYNC in a specific Google Home app.
> I confirmed that devices are allocated to rooms in my app on my iphone for the same home, but not allocated to rooms for the person who lives there.

Could you please confirm whether the user creates more than one 'Home' in GHA? roomHint is disabled for multi-Home users. Under this situation, they are required to allocate devices into rooms manually.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You are right. There are more than one "Home" in GHA. Once I remove other homes, I could see that devices are allocated into rooms automatically!!